# scatter plot with x value from row header

Tags: gnuplot, columnheader

I would like to plot data where multiple y-values exist for one x-value using gnuplot. The x-value is stored as a row header and the y-values are stored in the rows as shown schematically in the following table:

x1;   x2;   x3;   x4;   ...

y1,1; y2,1; y3,1; y4,1; ...

y1,2; y2,2; y3,2; y4,2; ...

y1,3; y2,3; y3,3; y4,3; ...

y1,4; y2,4; y3,4; y4,4; ...

y1,5; y2,5; y3,5; y4,5; ...

.;    . ;   .;    .;    ...

Is there a way of plotting these data without repeating the x-values?

Comment: If you can transpose your data file, then you can use `plot 'file' using 1:2, '' using 1:3` etc, or even iterate like `plot for [i=2:10] 'file' using 1:i`.

Comment: Thanks Christoph,

Unfortunately transposing does not work in my case, because there are additional data in separate segments of the file (separated by two empty lines), which have to be plotted as well. These data can be plotted at the moment with using `plot 'file' index 2 using 1:2`. Transposing the data would raise the same problem for that segment as I have at the moment with the first segment.

The hint regarding the `for` statement ist very helpful.

Comment: Then you'll need to transpose your data for every segment, and every segment must have the x-values once in the first column. With this you have some redundance regarding the x-values, but I don't see another way, except for using some external script to transform your original data in a proper format for gnuplot.

Comment: Thank you Christoph,
this ist not the answer I was hoping for. I will have a look, if I can do a work arround.

Comment: Yes, but that's the way gnuplot essentially works: it walks down row-by-row to generate a plot, and you specify the columns to use.